# roots of $Z^5=\sqrt{-3}$ roots of unity example

Tags: complex-analysis

roots of $Z^5=\sqrt{-3}$

---

letting $k=0,1,2,3,4$

$$Z_k= (\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{1}{5}} ie^{\frac{i2\pi k}{5}}$$

Comment: what is the question? :)

Comment: Im just checking if I did anything wrong

Comment: Add it to the question, otherwise it's hard to guess ... but it looks wrong so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{3}^\frac{1}{5}$ should be $3^\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: More likely it should be $3^{\frac1{10}}$ to account for the original square root.

Comment: You are right.  Also should be $e^{\frac{2\pi k}{10}}$ for k ranging from 0 to 9.

Comment: In the formulation given I would think that they mean only the one usual square root $\sqrt{-3}=i\sqrt3$, so only 5 solutions.